# Is there a good place in .vim folder to store text filters?

Tags: perl, vim, filter, latex

I would like to create a filter folder, best inside .vim and be able to run a text filter just with one file name:! filter.pl

I put up a Perl text filter to change all special Characters in a LaTeX Math Formula, which is running fine so far - only problem it is running on the whole line not the selected formula, but I can live with it ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -np

use strict;
use warnings;

# this filter transforms all special characters in Mathformular for LaTeX

s/\\/\\backslash /g;
s/([\$\#&%_{}])/\\$1/g;
```

But to call this filter is cumbersome

```
: '<,'>!"/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/my_vim_cheat_sheet/perl_filter.pl"
```

Apple put in the path to the iCloud a white space, so I have to put "" around! Where I put a collection of text filters?

Thank you for your answers

marek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely create a subfolder with any name different from ones Vim uses itself (see `:h 'rtp'`). So this is ok:

```
:*!$HOME/.vim/filters/perl_filter.pl
```

Also Vim has a predefined interface for a general purpose filter called 'equalprg'. To make use of it simply set a global-local (i.e. both `set` and `setlocal` are meaningful) option `equalprg` to a fully qualified name of your script. Then hit `=` in visual mode to apply filter (or `={motion}` in normal mode). (Read `:h 'equalprg'` `:h =`).

If you need several filters at once, and switching `equalprg` is not convenient, you can still try different options to reduce typing.

For example, mappings, such as

```
vnoremap <Leader>f :!/path/to/my/filter<CR>
```

Then hitting `\f` (or whatever is your "leader" key set) in the visual mode will result in the executing `:'<,'>!/path/to/my/filter` (note that the visual selection will be applied automatically).

Another attempt is to set a dedicated environment variable (which will be inherited by all child processes including shell(s). For example,

```
:let $filters = '~/.vim/filters'
:*!$filters/myfilter.pl
```

Of course, you can put those `set equalprg=...` `vnoremap ...` `let $filters=...` etc.etc. in your vimrc.

Comment: Thank you Matt! That means I would have to enter `:!~/.vim/filter/perl-filter.pl` ? Perhaps put a short cut or alias to this filter folder in .vimrc ? Any ideas?

Comment: Once again: this is a useful hint: `:help rtp` Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to create a filter folder, best inside `.vim` and be able to run a text filter just with one file name `:! filter.pl`

Simply add the script to somewhere within your `$PATH`. Or, if you really only intend to use that from within Vim, then add that directory to your `$PATH` in your `.vimrc`, so you have it available there.

For example, if you'd like to use `~/.vim/scripts` for your external Perl or shell scripts, you can use this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
call setenv('PATH', expand('~/.vim/scripts').':'.$PATH)
```

After that, you can simply use `:'<,'> !filter.pl` to run it. And Tab completion will work with the name of the script, type `:!fil<Tab>` and Vim will complete it to `filter.pl`, assuming it's a unique prefix.

The snippet above for your `.vimrc` has one minor issue, that if you `:source` your `.vimrc` during Vim runtime, it will keep adding the entry to `$PATH` multiple times. That doesn't typically break anything, only the entry will become longer, you might run into variable length issues.

You can fix it by checking whether that's present in path or not before updating it, perhaps with something like:

```
let scripts_dir = expand('~/.vim/scripts')
if index(split($PATH, ':'), scripts_dir) < 0
    call setenv('PATH', scripts_dir.':'.$PATH)
endif
```

---

But also, about this:

> I put up a Perl text filter to change all special Characters in a LaTeX Math Formula
>
> ```
> s/\\/\\backslash /g;
> s/([\$\#&%_{}])/\\$1/g;
> ```

Consider writing that in Vim instead.

In fact, almost the same syntax will work as a Vim function:

```
function! EscapeLatexMathFormula()
    s/\\/\\backslash /eg
    s/\([$#&%_{}]\)/\\\1/eg
endfunction
```

You can call it on a range, with:

```
:'<,'>call EscapeLatexMathFormula()
```

Calling it without a range will affect the current line only.

You can also make it into a command, with:

```
command! -range EscapeLatexMathFormula <line1>,<line2> call EscapeLatexMathFormula()
```

In which case you can simply use:

```
:'<,'>EscapeLatexMathFormula
```

You can use tab-completion for the function and command names (though, of course, you can pick shorter names if you'd like, as well.)

Note that user-defined command names need to start with an uppercase letter. Function names can start with an uppercase letter too (there are more options for function names, but making this global with an uppercase is probably the easiest here.)